# How does CPU handle overclocking

Tags: architecture, hardware, cpu-architecture

To my understanding, each stage in the datapath pipline takes an `ns` amount of seconds to execute and the clock cycle is set as close as possible to the execution time of the most expensive stage. What happens when the CPU is overclocked? How does it execute all of the stages on time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the clock cycle is set as close as possible to the execution time of the most expensive stage.

Yes, the critical path length determines the maximum possible clock speed, but power / cooling are also a limiting factor in setting the rated clock speed.

Vendors rate their CPUs to stay within a maximum electrical power consumption / thermal dissipation power (TDP) limit for *any* software workload at the rated clock speed, so they can guarantee reliable operation in a system with limited cooling, and so motherboard vendors know how good the voltage regulators need to be.

Higher clocks mean higher power, especially if voltage is also increased (which reduces the critical path length by reducing the gate-delay time).  But power scales with V<sup>2</sup>, and linearly with frequency, so overvolting can dramatically increase cooling requirements.  Higher temperatures increase the critical path length, IIRC.

Some overclockers only care about running games, which generate less heat than high-throughput 256b FMA code on all cores (like SuperPi), so limiting the software workload is one way to allow overclocking.

Even without limiting the workload, better cooling and power supply than the minimum requirements can allow overclocking even for max-power workloads like SuperPi, just with a different power / performance tradeoff than the vendor was aiming for.  (e.g. **running at max turbo for extended periods still counts as overclocking when it takes you outside the rated TDP and supply current envelope**.)

---

The other major reason that OCing works is that CPUs are sold with rated clock speeds lower than the theoretical max.  This is often for marketing reasons.  The silicon coming off the production line is binned according to how high it can clock.  But if more high-clock-capable chips are coming off the production line than there is market demand for, some of these chips will be sold as lower clock-speed parts (instead of reducing prices on the faster chips).  (Back in the day before locked clocks on all but the highest-end SKUs, this was the main reason for OCing.)

Notice that Intel for example only sells one (or two: i5 and i7) unlocked SKUs.  There is always going to be some variation from chip to chip within these bins.  Maybe you get an i7-6700k that has hardly any headroom to OC before the clock speed is too fast for the critical path (and you get data errors).  Or maybe you got lucky and the chip you bought is nearly perfect, and significantly better than the minimum threshold for that highest bin.